# How do I access remote CouchDB created with Bitnami

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, couchdb, bitnami, ssh-tunnel

I have setup a Bitnami CouchDB stack on AWS.  Everything seems fine in the AWS EC2 Console.  I have followed all the directions I can find about how to configure PuTTY for this implementation so that I can access CouchDB via SSH.  The PuTTY seems to work well also. I am able to SSH into the remote server and execute commands there, so I assume the SSH tunnel is working.  I followed these directions:
https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/access-ssh-tunnel/
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/administration/connect-remotely/

In order to access CouchDB, it appears that I must change the destination port (in PuTTY) to 5984, which I've done:
https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-access-couchdb-from-my-pc-https/53770/2

Then, I fire up PuTTY, and open the connection.  Again, it seems to work, but when I try and browse to ServerIP:5984, it never connects.  The best I can figure is that I need to somehow set Chrome to use the tunnel, but I don't know if that is right.

Any thoughts, suggestions, or redirections would be very helpful.

Thank you.

I'm at the end of my rope with this and am ready to try (shudder) installing CouchDB manually as it seems as though I am manually doing everything now and it still isn't working.

EDIT:
Here is what I have figured out: using PuTTY and the instructions I reference above, I can create an SSH tunnel.  Then, using Chrome, I go to my localhost:8888 (see my comment below--this is the local (ie. my windows machine) port connected via SSH to the remote (ie.server) port 5984) and it returns 'unauthorized'. If I use curl inside the PuTTY terminal window, and include my db credentials (ie. curl -X GET http://admin:{password}@localhost:5984), I can access CouchDB.  The question then becomes: how can I access CouchDB from Chrome AND insert my credentials (I've even tried Postman) so I can access Fauxton for testing and development purposes.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here, as you found, the server's ports are not open in the firewall by default. That's why we suggest the users to create a SSH tunnel to access the server. If you created the tunnel, you will need to use "localhost:5984" instead of "ServerIP:5984", this way you will use the SSH tunnel you already created to connect to the server. I hope this information helps

Comment: @Jota Martos Thanks for the reply.  I've noticed that you Bitnami Engineers are great at responding on the forums, and I appreciate it.  I should have mentioned that I am using a Windows machine and that I have a local installation of CouchDB, so when I do a localhost:5984 it shows me Fauxton for my local databases. But, in PuTTY if I set the Source Port to 8888 and the Destination Port to localhost:5984, and then browse (in Chrome) to localhost:8888 (which I thought would use the SSH tunnel and connect to server port 5984, it returns {"error":"unauthorized","reason":"Authentication required."

Answer (score 0):

So, I think I have this figured out.

The Bitnami docs help you properly configure PuTTY to enable an SSH tunnel between your local machine and the remote server (see: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/faq/get-started/access-ssh-tunnel/).  My understanding of this tunnel is that it creates a secure pipe between a specific port on your local machine, and a specific port on the remote server.  This tunnel is secured by the SSH keys you generate.  When I installed Bitnami CouchDB to AWS, the Bitnami console made the whole process very simple, including the SSH key generation process.  The Bitnami setup also created my CouchDB on the server, and secured it with a new admin password (more on this point later).

I then followed more directions that showed how to connect to CouchDB from a remote machine (see https://docs.bitnami.com/google/infrastructure/couchdb/administration/connect-remotely/).  This is where things go a little off the rails, or at least they did for me.  Bitnami (wisely) don’t recommend opening server ports to the outside world, but instead recommend the SSH tunnel method.  Makes sense.  However, the instructions on connecting remotely presume you WILL open the port in the firewall.  Once you figure out that you don’t want to do that and that you are not opening a port, but connecting securely via SSH, you have made progress, but are still only halfway there.

The SSH process to log into the server then works perfectly.  I open PuTTY, load the saved session and open the SSH and I’m in.  I can access the server and its files perfectly through the PuTTY terminal.  So, I then tried accessing CouchDB through Chrome.  In the address bar I typed:  http://localhost:8888.  This refers to MY localhost and port (ie. not the server’s) and NOT the server’s port.  The server’s port is mapped through the SSH tunnel config in PuTTY to 5984 (see: https://community.bitnami.com/t/cannot-access-couchdb-from-my-pc-https/53770).  This works but I get the message that authorization is needed.  This is because of the setup process which created an admin user and password, as well as a config issue, and this is the final piece of the puzzle (at least for me).

If you edit the local.ini file for CouchDB on the server, and change the [chttpd] value “require_valid_user=true” to “require_valid_user=false”, everything will work perfectly from your browser (once you have created the SSH tunnel of course) and you can access Fauxton.  I discovered this through some trial and error, but this post confirms it: https://blog.couchdb.org/2018/02/03/couchdb-authentication-without-server-side-code/.

I would still really appreciate any comments on this answer.  In particular, any comments about any possible security holes I may have created by changing require valid user to false.  I know this allows unauthenticated users to hit the database, but with the database secured by an admin password, the server secured by SSH, and with no firewall ports open, can someone even do that?

Comment: Hi again, I created the SSH tunnel and could obtain information from the app using the API and the command line: `curl http://user:PASSWORD@localhost:5984` and `curl http://user:PASSWORD@localhost:5984/_all_dbs`. However, I could not achieve that with the browser or when trying to connect to Fauxton. I'll forward the information to our engineering team and they will take a look at our configuration

Comment: Hi. I was able to connect using the Chrome plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en. In my case, the credentials were `user:elSonl16FRQr' so I had to add as a header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjplbFNvbmwxNkZSUXI=`. Then it worked